# GCP - How to see one VM costs in GCP? In billing account I see costs of all compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I'm looking for a way to find out how much I pay for my GCP VM instance.
I have 4 instances, and when I go to billing account -> Reports I see price for specific projects on Compute Engine in general.

My instance has windows and licensing, and custom type so I couldn't use the google calculator as well.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: i am wondering if the following would work, 1 add labels to your VM, 2 go to billing > reports and filter by group. To see labels at group make sure you have at least billing viewer on billing account. If somehow labels appear I am hoping you can track cost of each individual instance.

Comment: Exactly, @danyL! I have written a proper answer about this solution. I only noticed your comment after I finished writing so at least I can upvote you here. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try "Cost table" from Google Console > Billing > Cost table.

There you should configure your own filters, for example filter by project name, compute engine, sku description: instance.

There it will show you all of your instances with usage, cost and more information.

Comment: This works, but with 1 caveat - it's only for already invoiced past months. I could not find an option to show me the current month's costs.

Comment: I don't see "Cost table"

Answer (score 2):

You should assign your compute instances [labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) with different values to distinguish them.

For example, you can use a label named "instance" with a value equal to the instance name.

From the moment you do that you will be able to split the costs in the GCP Billing Report (but also in the BigQuery billing export data) by the instance name.

Here you can see that the label "instance" has been assigned to the compute instances on the 9th of March:

[image: GCP Billing Report example]

The costs per compute instance here include:

- cores,
- memory,
- disks,
- network egress.
- licenses, f.e. for Windows.

The "[Charges for other usage]" here are the costs of Compute Service not directly related to these machines, i.e. machines that do not have the "instance" label.

Comment: Should this work for any labels? I've just added instance labels and they don't show up in the group by option yet. However, I've used other labels such as  "os" or "version" that were useful to me which have existed for months - should I have expected to see these in the "group by" dropdown.

I'm in a corporate environment so it's possible not all billing reporting options are available to me.

Comment: Answered my own question: "Note: You must have billing-account-level permissions to set this option. Grouping by Labels is not available when viewing the report using project permissions only."

Answer (score -1):

you can enable resource level data which is available now and then put filter on decription via COMPUTE ENGINE and you will resource.name to get instance name and the do a aggregation and then vola